# UK Visa Application for Afghan Family holding Green Card

Tags: uk, standard-visitor-visas, application-status, us-residents, afghan-citizens

I have completed the UK visit Visa application for my self, wife and 3 children (6, years, 3 years and 2 years). I also paid the application fee and booked the appointment for Biometric at Spokane, USA. What are the next steps and how long does it take for the visas to be delivered to me?

Answer (score 1):

Your biometric confirmation receipt will be stamped at your appointment. You then have 5 days to mail this, your application form, your passport and supporting documents to VFS Services USA Inc. All applications must be accompanied by a valid passport with at least one page blank on both sides. If the application is mailed without a passport the application will be refused.

https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/usa-apply-for-a-uk-visa/apply-for-a-uk-visa-in-the-usa

Most visitor visa applications from Washington DC are processed within 30 days https://visa-processingtimes.homeoffice.gov.uk/y/washington-dc-united-states/visits-visas/general-visit-6-months-or-less